# How to change text colour in console application after its printed?

Tags: c#, console-application

I know this question is probably far-fetched, but if this feature is possible, that would be awesome. I want to change the colour of the text as the player is writing it, so if certain keywords are typed, they change to a certain colour.

I know you can change the cursor location, but I don't know if that is helpful in changing the colour. I also know you can do Console.Clear, but if possible I would like to not do that, since then I have to save the string and re-write it all, and its not to applicable/plausible to my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Generally no, because standard-output has historically been a write-only medium (think 1960s teleprinters).

Complicated answer: yes, thanks to the magic of `\r`.

Basically, you'd read what the user types on a per-keystroke basis and keep track of it yourself (perhaps in a `StringBuilder`), then if the user types in the magic-word then erase the previously printed line using `\r` (which moves the caret to the first column of the console without creating a new line) and then over-write what was previously printed there, but setting `Console.ForegroundColor` before re-printing it.

You don't need to manually print each keystroke yourself (until reprinting it with the highlight) as `Console.ReadKey` does not interfere with the otherwise normal operation of the console window and its local-echo behaviour.,

Here's something simple:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while( true ) {

    ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
    if( !Char.IsControl( key.KeyChar ) ) {

        sb.Append( key.KeyChar );
        if( sb.ToString() == "magic!" ) {

            Console.Write("\r");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.Write( sb.ToString() );
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
    } else {
        sb.Length = 0;
    }
}
```

This code is buggy and incomplete, but I think it demonstrates the underlying concept.

Comment: And to elaborate, there are the Console.CursorLeft and CursorTop properties that allow you to position where the text will be written within the window. So you can extent Dai's suggestion to rewrite the text anywhere on the console screen to achieve your goal. Of course, if the screen scrolls and moves the text you've already written, all bets are off. No one said console-based graphics was going to be easy. :)